# Reuse Alias on calculated field

Tags: mysql, subquery

Good afternoon, wonder if anyone could point me in the right direction as I am struggling a little. I have a mysql query that I need to include an alias in a calculated field as such:

```
 Select tblComms._CommMonth, 
        tblComms._Reference, 
        tblComms._ClientName, 
        tblComms._Premium, 
        tblComms._CommDue, 
        tblComms._Employee_Name, 
        tblCont.Retention, 
        (tblComms._CommDue) * (tblCont.Retention) / 100 As Paid, 
        (tblComms._CommDue) - (Paid) As Payable 
 From tblComms Inner Join dbo_companyref On 
      dbo_companyref._Reference = tblComms._Reference 
      Inner Join tblCont 
      On dbo_companyref._Advisor_Name = tblCont._Employee_Name
```

This returns an error "Unknown columns 'Paid' in field list", is there any way I can use the Paid alias after its been created at all? I am trying tp roll out a new system which was created in Access & SQL, they simply used saved queries / SPs for that..

Comment: Can you help me with the query?

Comment: The MS-Access alias feature is non-standard and will not work/compile for any other DBMS platform. You can create use-defined functions to accomplish the same things.

Comment: You can't use the alias in the select statement on Mysql, you'll have to recalculate it

Comment: @Juniad, I have edited original code to reflect actual sql query, sorry I should have [posted full code originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not allowed. You cannot use the column as an alias when the alias and other column are in the same level of `SELECT`.

You could have used the alias if it was something like this -

```
SELECT alias
FROM (SELECT column1 AS alias
      FROM table);
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your input, I managed to sort this by using mysql view, works a treat..

Answer (score 3):

You can use variables in mysql for this stuff:

```
Select tblComms._CommMonth, 
    tblComms._Reference, 
    tblComms._ClientName, 
    tblComms._Premium, 
    tblComms._CommDue, 
    tblComms._Employee_Name, 
    tblCont.Retention, 
    @Paid := (tblComms._CommDue) * (tblCont.Retention) / 100 As Paid, 
    (tblComms._CommDue) - (@Paid) As Payable From tblComms Inner Join dbo_companyref On 
  dbo_companyref._Reference = tblComms._Reference 
  Inner Join tblCont 
  On dbo_companyref._Advisor_Name = tblCont._Employee_Name
```

Answer (score -1):

use `(select Paid)`

```
 Select tblComms._CommMonth, 
    tblComms._Reference, 
    tblComms._ClientName, 
    tblComms._Premium, 
    tblComms._CommDue, 
    tblComms._Employee_Name, 
    tblCont.Retention, 
    (tblComms._CommDue) * (tblCont.Retention) / 100 As Paid, 
    (tblComms._CommDue) - (select Paid) As Payable 
  From tblComms Inner Join dbo_companyref On 
  dbo_companyref._Reference = tblComms._Reference 
  Inner Join tblCont 
  On dbo_companyref._Advisor_Name = tblCont._Employee_Name
```